# How can I translate text that I input into my Angularjs app?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to translate the text that I type into my input field to the language (German) I've taught my app in my appjs file, but it doesn't work. What I type into the input field is bound to the  tag area. That's where I want it to be translated, but it keeps coming out as English and I'm having a hard time figuring it out. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!--This is my HTML file-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <script         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js">.       </script>
    <script src="angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>

    </head>
    <body ng-init ="textToType">

        <!--This is where you type your text-->
        Text To Type: <input ng-model="textToType"/>

        <!--This is where your text needs to be translated-->
        <h1>{{textToType}}</h1>

        <br><br>

        <h1>{{ 'TITLE' | translate }}</h1>          
        <p>{{ 'FOO' | translate }}</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

```
  app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    'TITLE': 'Hello',
    'FOO': 'This is a paragraph'
  });

  $translateProvider.translations('de', {
    'TITLE': 'Hallo',
    'FOO': 'Dies ist ein Absatz'
  });

  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('de');
}]);
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding i18n. It is only for translating the text on fields or labels that your app uses like `TITLE` so people can use your app in their preferred language, it's not for translating free text like `textToTranslate`. You'll have to hook it up to some sort of translation API.

Comment: Well that would explain it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the `FOO` and `TITLE` examples worked:

```
<h1>{{ 'TITLE' | translate }}</h1>          
<p>{{ 'FOO' | translate }}</p>
```

I suggest trying the same `translate` filter for `textToType`:

```
<!--This is where your text needs to be translated-->
<h1>{{textToType | translate}}</h1>
```

Comment: One of the first things Ive tried but it didn't work.